# Codeigniter, Ajax: Pass html string from view to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass a long Html string from a view to a controller using an ajax call, so I can pass it further to another view.

Markup:

```
<a id="openPDF">Save as PDF</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#openPDF').click(function(){
    var htmlText = $( "div.modal" ).html();   //grab the html
    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify("{strData : '" + htmlText + "' }");
    console.log(dataToSend );   // contains the json 
    $.ajax({ 
       url: "/dashboard/pdf",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       data: dataToSend
       success: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); },
       error: function (type) { alert("ERROR!" + type.responseText); }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function pdf(){
    $data['htmlString'] = json_decode($this->input->post('strData'));
    $this->load->view('pdf', $data);
    }
```

My ajax call doesn't work because when a click the `#openPDF` button i get the alert error:

`ERROR! NULL`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting your headers properly before writing the output?

Controller:

```
public function pdf() {
    $data['htmlString'] = json_decode($this->input->post('strData'));
    $viewString = $this->load->view('pdf', $data, true); // this returns view as string rather than outputting it

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['viewString' => $viewString]);
}
```

In client-side js, you can pass this `success` function to `$.ajax()`

```
success: function (response) {
    if ('undefined' !== typeof response.viewString) {
        // append view to concerned element 
        $('#viewTarget').append(response.viewString);
    } else {
        console.log('response did not contain viewString');
    }
},
```

I hope this helps.

**Also:**

Navigate directly to the url (the one you are sending an ajax request for) in your browser and see if you get a valid json output.